# Combination of Field values and static text in Process Builder

Tags: workflow, flow, process-builder

Lets say whenever the opportunity is Closed Won , a Case needs to be created for the same with a Subject of : Opportunity "Opportunity_name" has been closed won . I have created a process using the process builder and specified the action as Record Creation . Is it possible to have a field value as static text + some field values ?

Comment: Did you got any workaround for this?

Comment: Nope nothing as far as i know!!

Answer (score 2):

It would have been possible to launch a flow that would allow for this type of functionality when this was first posted.

Here's how you can accomplish this with the most recent set of updates (Summer '15):

1. Select the "Opportunity Object and "When a record is created or edited."
2. Select that the conditions are met for the criteria node

   a. Stage has the value of "Closed Won"

   b. Select the advanced section and "execute actions only when specified changes are made to the record."
3. Select the "create a record" option in the immediate actions.

   a. Select the record type to be "Case".

   b. Set the status and other default values.

Note: Record type above is not equal to "record type" the field, but the type of record being created.

c. For subject, put in: [Opportunity].Name & " has been closed won."
  Use this formula and save.

[image]

Activate the process and test.

Make sure to migrate from a sandbox to production after running all tests in a sandbox environment to ensure no issues with apex (code may need to be updated to accommodate the processes - mostly because of validations / incomplete data in test classes).

Answer (score 0):

For your static text, did you try using a $Label global variable? I haven't had the need to do this in Process Builder yet, but I know it can be used (see this post on using $Label in PB for creating a line break: [Adding a Line Break in Process Builder Formula](http://automationchampion.com/2015/08/06/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-40-adding-a-line-break-in-process-builder-formula/)

'Hope this helps!